# Calculate whitespace between flex item implicitly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, whitespace, padding

I have a flex container with 3 flex items and need to place an absolutely positioned div over the last item. and add an effect such the left padding of it is exactly one half of the space between the flex-items .
I solved it with calculating values explicitly .
I would like to know if the calc can be simplified but avoiding the part of subtracting parent - sum of child width .
**If there some property which gives you the whitespace value in a flex container ?**

Or is there a better way to achieve the same .

```css
*{
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.parent{

  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  position:relative;
}
.child{
  font-size:14px;
  width:50px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
.pop-over{
  box-sizing:content-box;
  width:50px;
  height:120%;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:.5;
  padding-left:calc((100% - 150px) / 4)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
Child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
   <div class="child">
     Child
  </div>
  <div class="pop-over">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, there is no property or anything like that.

Comment: If it's always gone popover the last child? If, is it a option to place the pop-over inside that child?

Comment: you alread got the right calculation for the whitespace, why you think there is a better way if this one is working good?

Comment: I had just given a sample , my layout is more complex than that , it consists multiple flex-rows of equal size and number of items (like a table) and I want the popover effect for the last column in the table  . Adding an extra div or trying to someone group the last column items disturbs my layout . So I went for the absoulte and calc solution . But I just want to get rid of calc if possible because it looks like I am tying up  layout values very tightly